# Is necessary send email with ActiveJob if I'm using deliver_later method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

If I am using `deliver_later` method to send an asynchronous email, do I need to generate an `ActiveJob` class to perform it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `deliver_later` no need to create an ActiveJob class as **Action mailer is already integrated with ActiveJob** and emails will be sent asynchronously through the default queue `mailers`. But if you want to run specific methods then you create ActiveJob class and use `perform_later`.

**Reference:**
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#action-mailer

Create job if using `perform_later`:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#create-the-job

Comment: Is there a differentiation as to when you would deliver an email by calling the mailer directly using `deliver_later` or create a job using `perform_later`? Or are they completely identical?